# Identify this thriller revenge movie

Tags: identify-this-movie

If I remember correctly, it is a movie about a man getting revenge by killing off another family.

The main character is short and caucasian.
It begins with him being shown as a homeless man with a beard.
He learns that someone who has caused him harm is getting out of prison.
He follows the man to a bar and when the man is in the bathroom, he kills him by stabbing him.
He runs away by taking one of the cars outside.

Other random scenes I remember:

He is in either his sister's or his ex-wife's house after he kills the man, because he assumes they will come after him. They do, and he gets away but gets shot with a crossbow to his thigh.

After that shootout, he takes one of the guy that game to get him and locks him in his car trunk.

He finds an old friend and asks him for help, and the friend gives him a gun.

The main character confronts the guy in his trunk but is tricked and has his own gun pointed on him by the guy who was in the trunk.  He is about to get shot but his same friend saves him by shooting down the trunk guy from far away.  I specifically remember this scene as his friend's first shot barely missed.  We could hear the sound of the bullet against the wind before we heard the actual gun shot since the shot came from far away. But the second shot kills the man.

The ending scene was with him waiting at the other family's house when they are not there.  He buries the members he has killed.  He waits for them at their house until they return. When they come back, they do not know he is there.  But they are angry at what he has done and are swearing to kill him. He then ambushes them.  It ends with him killing them and then dying.  But he lets one of the family member go (a teenage boy).

What movie was this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for [Blue Ruin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Ruin) from 2013. The vagrant at the beginning, Dwight, gets information that the man who killed his parents, Wade, is getting out of prison. Dwight finds Wade and kills him. He then protects himself, his sister and her family from Wade's family. Eventually, he does end up letting the youngest of Wade's family go because it turns out they are actually related.

Comment: Definitely this!